# find the adapter that references a table in epicor

Tags: vb.net, dataset, adapter, epicorerp

In Epicor 9.05 I need to get to the Part Mtl table from the Quote Entry Script. I looked in the PartAdapter but it doesn't seem to have the PartMtl table in its dataset. Which adapter has the partmtl in its dataset? More generally, how do I find which adapters will contain which tables? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woohoo I found it. In Epicor 9.05 create a dummy BAQ in the BAQ designer. Go to the Phrase Builder tool, and there should be button that says "Business Objects...". If you click on that, it opens up a pop up window with a tree of all the business objects in Epicor. You can expand each node to see the underlying Epicor tables which exist as part of that Business Object.

Enjoy oh you few Epicor customization developers!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the tool to add the necessary assemblies from the 'compiler' if I Can call it that.

Tools>Wizards>Assembly Reference Manager